# How to customize the border color, width, and height of Material-UI Text Field with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, components, textfield, styled-components

I'm getting a bit confused about how to customize Material-UI components. I've read through the docs and a team member said that they use styled-components.
I'm trying to change

- the border color of a Text Field component to #cbb0b0
- width be 200px
- height be 60 px.

I've tried various things for hours and still haven't figured it out. I'm admitting defeat and asking for help!

Here's what I'm trying to modify:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'; 

export default function InputBox () {
  return (
    <TextField 
      id="outlined-basic"
      variant="outlined"
      label="Default"
      defaultValue="Input Text"
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC `styled-components` is not a requirement for you. MUI has several built-in ways to override styles, you can learn more about it [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#customizing-components). Alternatively you can look at the many code examples for each component, which almost always include style overrides (click on the *Show full source icon*). In this case, [Text Fields](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/).

To make it a bit more obvious in my example below, I changed the style values, you just need to put in your own.

```js
const { TextField, makeStyles } = MaterialUI

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  input: {
    width: 400,
    height: 150,
    '& input + fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'hotpink',
    },
  },
});

function InputBox() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      InputProps={{
        className: classes.input,
      }}
      id="outlined-basic"
      variant="outlined"
      label="Default"
      defaultValue="Input Text"
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<InputBox />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<div id="root"></div>
```